# Site unreacable after mapping domain DNS to AWS Elastic IP

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I am following different tutorials to have my blog setup and working. I installed the WP on AWS which was working fine. Then I created Elastic IP and used that IP in my domain dns (hover.com). I used following entries

```
hostname > www

recordtype > A

value = <my_elastic_ip>
```

after that, I changed the site url in my wordpress site as well. to confirm if the address has been changed or not, i issued following command to see what is listed

```
[aws_ssh_connection ~]$ curl localhost | grep wp-content
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7965  100  7965    0     0  56891      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 57302
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stock-style-css'  href='http://www.<my_domain>/wp-content/themes/stock/style.css?ver=4.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.<my_domain>/wp-content/themes/stock/js/navigation.js?ver=20120206'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.<my_domain>/wp-content/themes/stock/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20130115'></script>
```

so it shows that the site address is changed but when i enter my domain address in browser, it tries to connect to my domain and then gives error **The webpage isn't available**

Also, i did check [whats my dns is resolved](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) to and it shows the elastic IP address. So i assume it has been configured properly?

Did i do something wrong ? Or do i have to wait sometime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. While assigning new IP i hadn't associated the IP with the instance. Its all good :)